# Multiple languages in website

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm developing a website that will have support for 16 different languages(bengali, korean, japanese, arabic, hebrew...) and in some machines, some of these languages are displayed as squares.
I've checked the encoding of the page and everything seems to be working as it should, the headers are being sent correctly stating the encoding as utf-8, mb_detect_enconding outputs "utf-8".

This problem just happens in some computers, and so far I managed to found two different solutions. The first in WinXP enabling aditional languages in control panel, and the second, by adding google fonts to the website, which makes 3 different languages appear correctly.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue or the cause of it?

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was on missing fonts. The solution was to use fonts.com service or  a webfont/font file that contained the needed characters.

Comment: I think you should check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). I also don't think it's your problem to solve a client's computer problem. They should just configure it properly. On a side note, I've not seen many people who have their computers not configured to read their favorite language. Well that's my opinion.

Comment: "some of these languages are displayed as squares" This means there is not font on that system to support the language you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hai some languages requires special encoding like arabic.
if you wanted to add arabic heres the PHP code for it

```
                <?php 

      header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
      echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
      echo '<body dir="rtl">';

?>
```

thats all I know I hope it helped you :D.